# Disable Error Logging In Laravel 4.2 When Environment is Local

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-4

I've seen a couple posts around here that tell me how to disable logging. Most of them say I have to comment out a few lines in `app/start/global.php`, and so I did:

```
// $logFile = 'laravel.log';
// Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);

App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code){ 
    // Log::error($exception);
});
```

My concern is that information still gets written to the log file, say when I navigate to a route that doesn't exist. I've also tried changing *when* the information is written to the log, for example:

```
if(App::environment() == "local"){
    Log::info("Error Ignored. Environment: Local");
} else {
    Log::error($exception);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to affect anything at all. If I get an error, it still logs the full error, and I know my environment is `local` by running `php artisan env`.

Lastly, I don't want to turn `'debug' => false,` as I would never be able to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

After any config changes, it's usually a good idea to run the following commands:

`php artisan optimize & php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Good suggestion, but I tired running those two (along with `php artisan dump-autoload`) and tried again: still getting error messages.